# MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification is not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I added a notification with the following code,

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoLoadingComplete)
                                           name:MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification
                                          object:self.streamPlayer];
```

but it did not enter in the `videoLoadingComplete` function even after the video stars playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviestart:)   name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
 -(void)moviestart
{
//your code here
}
```